# Vim-Sexp - How do I move each inner form to a new line?

Tags: vim, clojure, lisp

I have the awesome [vim-sexp](https://github.com/guns/vim-sexp) and [vim-sexp-mappings-for-regular-people](https://github.com/tpope/vim-sexp-mappings-for-regular-people) plugins installed, and I've come across a situation I'm not sure how to solve.

Suppose I have the following form:

```
(alimony barbara (code determinant) eclair final-countdown)
```

How can I transform that to:

```
(alimony
  barbara
  (code determinant)
  eclair
  final-countdown)
```

I can go ahead and insert a newline before every inner-form/element, but that is a bit tedious. There should be a way with or without the sexp plugin

Comment: `'<,'>s/\s/\r/g`. Of course, `(code determinant)` you have to take care of yourself. jk

Comment: I love vim, and use Cursive with vim-mode in IntelliJ IDEA now. However, it can't read your mind, and for this type of transform you have to insert the <cr>'s manually. It may be the same for your situation.

Comment: I am not aware of a way to do it out of the box. Since a regexp would also mess with indenting (which is ok, if you use e.g. fireplace and just reformat the outer form) -- beside messing the inner form up --, i'd go with: cursor somewhere in `alimony`, `E` to go the the end of same level element, then `a<CR><ESC>` (append newline), then repeat `E.` (end-of-element, repeat insert newline)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an old question, but maybe an updated answer will help someone who comes here in the future.

You don't have to write the program mentioned by Kaz.  Others have already done it.  I have not tried them, but here are a few:
[fipp](https://github.com/brandonbloom/fipp),
[cljfmt](https://github.com/weavejester/cljfmt),
[cljstyle](https://github.com/greglook/cljstyle),
[zprint](https://github.com/kkinnear/zprint),
[joker](https://github.com/candid82/joker).  (The last one does more than code formatting.)

As Kaz suggests, once installed, you can pipe code to a formatter using `!`.  You can even bind this operation to a key combination.  Some of the formatters offer suggestions about how to do this sort of thing.

In addition, some vim IDE plugins, such as [vim-iced](https://liquidz.github.io/vim-iced/#formatting_customize) provide support for using an external formatter.

Answer (score 0):

A productive way to get this behavior would be, rather than fighting with Vim modules and extensions, to write a Lisp program which reads S-expressions and outputs them reformatted in the desired way. To use that program out of Vim, just pipe a range of lines into it using the `!` command.